# "find: bad option -name "*.user"" while passing variables to find

Tags: bash, find

In a bash script this fails:

```
fileloc='/var/adm/logs/morelogs'
filename=' -name "*.user"'

fileList="$(find "$fileloc"/* -type f -prune "$filename" -print)"


find: bad option  -name "*.user"
find: [-H | -L] path-list predicate-list
```

but this works:

```
find /var/adm/logs/morelogs/* -type f -prune -name "*.user" -print
```

in the same  manner:
this fails:

```
fileloc='/var/adm/logs/morelogs'
filename='\( -name "admin.*" -o -name "*.user" -o -name "*.user.gz" \)'

fileList="$(find "$fileloc"/* -type f -prune "$filename" -print)"


find: bad option  \( -name "admin.*" -o -name "*.user" -o -name "*.user.gz" \)
find: [-H | -L] path-list predicate-list
```

but this works:

```
find /var/adm/logs/morelogs/* -type f -prune \( -name "admin.*" -o -name "*.user" -o -name "*.user.gz" \) -print
```

GNU bash, version 3.00.16(1)-release-(sparc-sun-solaris2.10)

Comment: Don't do this. See [I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you're trying to build the list of names to search for dynamically -- if this is the case, a variant of @anubhava's answer using the array for just the name patterns is the best approach:

```
namepatterns=() # Start with no filenames to search for
while something; do
    newsuffix="whatever"
    namepatterns+=(-o -name "*.$newsuffix")
done

# Note that "${namepatterns[@]}" is not quite what we want to pass to find, since
# it always starts with "-o" (unless it's empty, in which case this'll have other
# problems). But "${namepatterns[@]:1}" leaves off the first element, and gets us
# what we need.
fileList="$(find "$fileloc"/* -type f -prune "(" "${namepatterns[@]:1}" ")" -print)"
```

Other notes: I second @BroSlow's recommendation to read [BashFAQ #50: I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050), and also you're going to have trouble using that filelist variable if any of the filenames contain funny characters (esp. whitespace and wildcards) -- see [BashFAQ #20: How can I find and safely handle file names containing newlines, spaces or both?](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/020) (short answer: arrays are better for this as well!)

Answer (score 3):

This is usecase when you should use BASH arrays or BASH function.

Using BASH arrays:

```
#!/bin/bash

# initialize your constants
fileloc='/var/adm/logs/morelogs'
filename='*.user'

# create an array with full find command
cmd=( find "$fileloc" -type f -prune -name "$filename" -print )

# execute find command line using BASH array
"${cmd[@]}"
```

Comment: I never understood why op wanted the `-name` in a variable.

Comment: -name is in variable because script runs on many servers and filenames to search are not constant, they are obtained after checking into the filesystem

Comment: Yes that is understood to have `'*.user'` or `'*.foo'` or  `'*.txt'` in the `filename` variable. But you don't really need `-name` in `filename` variable.

Answer (score 2):

Lets see what are you doing with `set -x`:

```
$ fileloc='/var/adm/logs/morelogs'
+ fileloc=/var/adm/logs/morelogs
$ filename=' -name "*.user"'
+ filename=' -name "*.user"'
```

Everything seems fine, now, next line:

```
$ fileList="$(find "$fileloc"/* -type f -prune "$filename" -print)"
++ find '/var/adm/logs/morelogs/*' -type f -prune ' -name "*.user"' -print
find: paths must precede expression:  -name "*.user"
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec] [path...] [expression]
+ fileList=
```

I think you see the problem, if you execute `find '/var/adm/logs/morelogs/*' -type f -prune ' -name "*.user"' -print` it will throw you an error:

```
$ find '/var/adm/logs/morelogs/*' -type f -prune ' -name "*.user"' -print
find: paths must precede expression:  -name "*.user"
Usage: find [-H] [-L] [-P] [-Olevel] [-D help|tree|search|stat|rates|opt|exec] [path...] [expression]
```

What's happening? Well, there's a bunch of single quotes that are in the way, but the one that causes problems is the two lasts, before `-name` and `-print`, which cause find to see it as a single parameter, the other can be ignored. So, how to fix this? Don't use double quotes to ask for the `$filename` variable:

```
$ find "$fileloc" -type f -prune $filename -print
+ find /var/adm/logs/morelogs -type f -prune -name '*.user' -print
```

That should solve it.

Comment: i did try a lot of things. 1) removing quotes as you suggested. first command does not give any error, but does not produce any output into array either. second command with multiple names does not work and still gives err : bad option \\(. 2) changing all single quotes to double-quotes (and escaped), that does not work either.

Answer (score 0):

not an answer to problem, but a poor solution. After getting frustrated, i just hard-coded the search to have full options list.

so it looks like this now: and it works. i had to build some cases, and repeat myself - not a good programming practice, but i was tired of this shell ting....

so for example one option looks like:

```
fileList="$(find "$fileloc"/* -type f -prune \( -name "admin.*" -o -name "*.user" -o -name "*.user.gz" \) -print)"
```